Why isn't the original EM wave in a beam of light in a medium not still detectable from a distance as if it were moving at the speed of light?
I'm learning optics and I've been told that the reason light slows down in glass is because the Electromagnetic field of a beam of light interacts with and accelerates charged electrons in  glass molecules which then generate their own photons and the combined wave resulting from the interference of the beam and these photons have a slower group velocity, hence the light travels slower.
The explanation given is that even though all the components of this combined wave travel at the speed of light, all together the combination moves at a slower pace. I've seen the sine sum formulas for this and it makes sense how the combined wave has a lower velocity, however to me it still seems like we should be able to detect the original wave when it's first coming towards us at a large distance as if it were still travelling at $c$ and so "detect" the presence of the light beam before it reaches us.
For a concrete example consider a block of glass (refractive index $n=1.5$) of length $c$ with a light source at one end and a detector at the other. Since light travels at $\frac{2}{3}c$ in the glass we'd expect it to take $1.5$ seconds to detect the signal. However equally you can argue that the direct component of the beam of light is still moving at $c$ so the detector should be able to notice a disturbance in the EM field after $1$ second and can thus "detect" that the source was has been fired before the light from the source reaches it.
I don't know which of these two arguments is correct, I suspect the former one but I can't see where the second one goes wrong. Any help clearing up my intuitions is much appreciated!

However equally you can argue that the direct component of the beam of light is still moving at $c,\dots$ so this component of the beam does not interact with the medium.

From a particle point of view, when photons of the incoming beam scatter off electrons, they do not keep going in the same direction. The mean direction of photon travel is still in the same, though.

this has nothing to do with photons propagating, see the Brillouin - Sommerfeld precursor theory in Jackson chapter 7.11 and also in Loudon

Light interference is a convenient method at the high school level to explain the double slit experiment and other phenomenon ... it works fairly well and with the Huygens principle there are many math problems and exams that can be created.  Your textbook was written with many concepts from the early 1900s .... most/all concepts are valid but the interference concept is  problematic when taken literally.
Photons never cancel each other, that would be a violation of conservation of energy, all photons take preferred paths as dictated by the EM field.   Interference is a much broader term in advanced physics, it is best considered as EM field affects, and with the photon as a local wave in the EM field.
